# VBA code breaks after first run - Error 91

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to semi-automate a file by using code to insert/copy/paste values and formulas. When I run this code once, it works fine. Trying to run the code any subsequent time results in a "run-time error '91'." Debugging the error highlights the code in which I try to use the phrase 'na.Row' to recall the row number identified earlier in the code.

Note: I am extremely new to VBA and have no prior coding background; I'm sure it could be much more clean and concise.

```
Sub AdvtoStd_Click()

'Names the Worksheets

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Org")

    Dim ar As Worksheet
    Set ar = Worksheets("Adv. Retrieve")

    Dim sr As Worksheet
    Set sr = Worksheets("Std. Retrieve")


'Finds the cell with 'No_Account' and names it id

    Dim na As Range
    Set na = ws.Range("A:A").Find("No_Account", LookIn:=xlValues)

    Dim Aacts As Range
    Set Aacts = ar.Range("A:A").Find("Accounts", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)


'Clears the old numbers on the Retail worksheet

    Worksheets("Retail").Activate
    Range("A4:E2000").ClearContents

'Copies the accounts from the Org to Retail worksheet

    ws.Range("A4:A2000").Copy
    Sheets("Retail").Range("A4:A2000").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Inserts the VLookup into cells B4 and C4 + Inserts the Variance calculation in cell E4
'Copies the VLookup and Variance calculation down to 'No_Account'

    Sheets("Retail").Range("B4").Value = "=VLOOKUP(A4,'Adv. Retrieve'!A:I,3,FALSE)"
    Sheets("Retail").Range("C4").Value = "=VLOOKUP(A4,'Std. Retrieve'!A:I,3,FALSE)"
    Sheets("Retail").Range("E4").Value = "=C4-B4"
    Sheets("Retail").Range("B4:E4").Copy
    Sheets("Retail").Range("B5", Sheets("Retail").Range("E" & na.Row)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

'Calculates the TOTALs

    Sheets("Retail").Range("B" & na.Row + 2).Value = "=SUM(OFFSET(B1,,,ROW()-1,1))"
    Sheets("Retail").Range("C" & na.Row + 2).Value = "=SUM(OFFSET(C1,,,ROW()-1,1))"

'Copies the Hyperion values

    ar.Range("B" & Aacts.Row).Copy
    Sheets("Retail").Range("B" & na.Row + 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

The error occurs in the part of the code in which I am trying to paste formulas in columns `B:E` down to the row number in which Account Names end in column `A`.

Like I mentioned earlier, the code works exactly as desired when I open the file and run it once, but any secondary attempt to run the code produces the error '91'.

Comment: You have a few unqualified ranges, make sure you always give the sheet you expect the range to be on.  What line throws the error, the `.PasteSpecial` line?  Finally, what happens if `na` is `Nothing` ?  Add `Debug.Print na.Row` right before the `copy/paste` lines and see what is output the second time. I'm betting there's no row.

Comment: You need to code for the possibility of `na` & `Aacts` not being found. `If Not na is Nothing Then....`. If your value is not found your paste line is actually being read as `Range("B" & Nothing + 2).Value = .....` and that's just nonsense. Def error worthy :P

Comment: "'Finds the cell with 'No_Account' and names it id": Although I cannot see in the code where this is done, but if you have done it, it might be possible that you don't have any cells with 'No_Account' anymore, which would mean "na=Nothing".

Comment: @urdearboy If I'm understanding correctly, you are saying I need to add code in the case that "No_Account" and/or "Accounts" can't be found? That makes sense, but the entirety of the code relies on them being found; they should always be found in order to identify the row number I need later on in the code.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Sorry, that is just a typo in the comment. 'id' should actually read as 'na'

Comment: @cpk24. Right after you `Set na` try `Msgbox na` - if you get an error on the added line, then the issue is in fact that `na` is not being found. What you are saying only drives my point. If your code is dependent on these values being found, it follows that the code will have issues if they are **not** found.

Comment: @urdearboy Okay, I added the message box and it looks like you are correct. The first time I ran it, I got a message box with the text 'No_Account'. The second time I ran it, I got an error on the Msgbox na line of code. Do you know why this could be happening? Nothing is changing on the Org. worksheet in which I am using code to find the text 'No_Account'. The words 'No_Account' are still on the Org. worksheet.

Comment: You're looking for `No_Account` on worksheet `Org`, but then using the row number on sheet `Retail`.  What sheet does the `No_Account` exist on?

Comment: @tigeravatar When I am finding the cell it is only on the Org sheet. It then gets copy and pasted with the entirety of column A, to the Retail sheet. It's location remains the same on both sheets. But yes I am aware that I am finding it on the Org sheet and then using that row number on the Retail sheet.

Comment: You have a unqualified `ClearContents` in your code. After you run the code once, can you verify the values in question actually still exist or are you just assuming?

Comment: I can verify that the value "No_Account" does in fact still exist on the Org worksheet after running the code once @urdearboy